# How to get SAML Response and SAML Token in Controller Action method

Tags: sustainsys-saml2

I am using this code in CALLback url using `SUstainsys.SAaml2` library:

```
 public ActionResult Callback()
    {

        var samlToken = (Saml2SecurityToken)null;
        var samlResponses =  HttpContext.Request.Form["SAMLResponse"];  HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["SAMLResponse"]; or elsewhere.
        //if (form.Count() > 0)
        //{
        //    var samlResponses = form.GetValues("SAMLResponse");
            if (samlResponses != null)
            {
                foreach (var samlResponse in samlResponses)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var decodedSamlResponse = Convert.FromBase64String(samlResponse.ToString());
                        var reader = XmlReader.Create(new MemoryStream(decodedSamlResponse));
                        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlElement));
                        var samlResponseElement = (XmlElement)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                        var manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(samlResponseElement.OwnerDocument.NameTable);
                        manager.AddNamespace("saml2", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion");
                        var assertion = (XmlElement)samlResponseElement.SelectSingleNode("//saml2:Assertion", manager);
                    //var samltoken= Options.FromConfiguration.SPOptions.Saml2PSecurityTokenHandler.ReadToken(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(assertion.OuterXml)));
                    samlToken = (Saml2SecurityToken)Options.FromConfiguration.SPOptions.Saml2PSecurityTokenHandler.ReadToken(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(assertion.OuterXml)));
                        break;
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            }
        ViewBag.SamlResponse = samlResponses;
        ViewBag.SamlToken = samlToken;
        return View();
    }
```

But I am getting null in SAML Response.

Answer (score 0):

That functionality is built into the `AcsCommand`, you shouldn't do it yourself.

Look at the samples in the repo and use the HttpModule, Mvc Controller or Owin middleware (depending on what kind of application you have).

Comment: Hi Abel,
Actual problem is :

Comment: I am new to SAML. Requirement is to get SAML token from SAML Response in controller action method and to pass that token to ImanageClient.
Can you help me in this how I can get SAML token from SAML response in c#.

The above code is not working as I am not getting response in request.form.

Instead I can check SAMl response in chrome extention tool.Please help!!

Comment: @HitanshuSharma did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do the same thing.